# node.js broadcast function is not consistently broadcasting to all connected clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, broadcast

I am trying to create 8 tcp socket connections to 8 tcp clients. I receive messages from a websocket client and broadcast each message to the 8 tcp clients. Intermittently, the broadcast does not broadcast to all 8 tcp clients. Can't figure out what I am doing incorrectly.

```
    var tcpclients = [];

    var server = new net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.pipe(socket);
    tcpclients.push(socket);
    pushed++;
    console.log("pushed=%d", pushed);
    if (pushed == 8) {
        broadcast(UP);
        pushed = 0;
    }

    socket.on('data', function(message) {
        console.log("RECVD: %d image bytes from tcp client", message.length);
        ws.send(message);
    });

    socket.on('end', function(message) {
        console.log("TCP socket closed", arguments);
    });

    socket.on('error', function() {
        console.log("TCP connection error", arguments);
    });
    }).listen(tcpport, host, function() {
       console.log('TCP connection open');
    });
```

message is being received from the websocket client and then broadcast using function broadcast(message).

```
    function broadcast(message) {
    if (tcpclients.length === 0) {
        console.log("no tcp clients active");
        return;
    }
    console.log("broadcast to %d server ranks", tcpclients.length);
    tcpclients.forEach(function(client, index, array) {
        client.write(message);
        console.log("SENT:" + message.length + " message bytes to TCP      client");
    });
    }
```

Comment: How do you know the data isn't sent?  You're not seeing your `console.log()` message?  What have you done to test this?  Also, have you fired up a packet sniffer like Wireshark to see what's going on?

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding so quickly. I am not seeing my 8 expected console.log("SEND:" + .....) messages and the application I'm broadcasting data to is not receiving the 8 broadcast messages. I have not tried a packet sniffer like Wireshark, but I will now that you've recommended it.